# How to refresh a sharepoint list from C# console application

Tags: development, splist, sharepoint-library, ssom, refresh

Is there any way to refresh a SharePoint list from C# console application.

**NOTE:** By refresh I mean the same that we achieve by doing a `Ctrl + F5`.

Comment: Hi. This is not clear. Refresh from console? What are you tring to do?

Comment: I am inserting some data in a Sharepoint list from my C# console application. When I am running the .exe of my app, only some fields of the list are getting populated.However, when I am debugging to find out where I am actually missing, all the list fields are getting populated properly without any issue...that's why I am thinking that refreshing the list might be one of the possible solutions.

Comment: Can you post your code? Are you using item.update() ?

Comment: Tried item.update()...still facing same problem

Comment: Please pust your code

Answer (score 0):

Tarun-

Your console application and your browser are two different process. When your console application is successful in adding list item, you need to manually refresh the browser to see the latest changes.
What is your business case, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Instead of refreshing 'manually'...how to achieve it through code??

Comment: It's really complicated to hook into existing browser process and fire an refresh event. Look for alternate option for your console application, Try to create a web form instead, on successful item add redirect the page to the actual list.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `list.Update` method to update the changes done to the list. It is same as refreshing. Please read this article [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.update.aspx)
 If you want this to be done in periodically. Add the timer and call this method between specific intervals.

Comment: tried...but still getting same issue